# How do I switch Ruby system back to 1.8.7 using RVM?

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

If I run:

```
rvm system
ruby -v
```

I get:

```
ruby-192...
```

I want the system version that is Ruby 1.8.7.

Ruby 1.9.2 was installed using RVM. I still can see Ruby 1.8.7 if I run `/usr/bin/ruby -v`.

rvm info

```
system:

  system:
    uname:       "Darwin MacML.local 11.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 11.2.0: Tue Aug  9 20:54:00 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1699.24.8~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin11)"
    zsh:         "/bin/zsh => zsh 4.3.11 (i386-apple-darwin11.0)"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.10.0 by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]"

  homes:
    gem:          "not set"
    ruby:         "not set"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/usr/local/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/usr/local/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/usr/local/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/usr/local/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/ML/.rvm/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     ""
    GEM_PATH:     ""
    MY_RUBY_HOME: ""
    IRBRC:        ""
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

Comment: You have a number of variables that are not set and your PATH is not correct for how RVM would initialize it. Try opening a new shell, and rerun `rvm info` in that window and compare it to this one. It should look very different if RVM is being initialized correctly. Also, notice that you have a Ruby in `/usr/local/bin`, which is not standard on MacOS.

Comment: Try `rvm system;which ruby;/usr/local/bin/ruby -v;/usr/bin/ruby -v`. I think your `/usr/local/bin/ruby` is 1.9.2 and confusing you.

Comment: Also the output of `rvm list` would be useful

Comment: /usr/local/bin/ruby -v => ruby 1.9.2p136 (2010-12-25 revision 30365) [x86_64-darwin10.4.0] ---------
/usr/bin/ruby -v => ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0] ---------
so how do I remove the 1.9.2??

Comment: "so how do I remove the 1.9.2??", depends on how you installed it, and whether you want a permanent removal or temporary. Sounds like you're hacking on your system without really understanding what you're doing. It would help if you added how 1.9.2 came to be on your system in `/usr/local/bin`. Add the information to your question by editing it and appending. Please don't add it to comments because it makes it too hard for us to locate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem were these 2 lines below on my .profile

> export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
>
> export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH

I commented both and the path to the system ruby went back to normal. the Tin Man tip was crucial to find what the problem was.

I had one ruby version in /usr/local/bin/ruby and another in /usr/bin/ruby

After I commented the lines mysql stopped working by I reinstalled with brew and everything seems to be working

Comment: The reason MySQL stopped working was because you disabled it in your PATH: `/usr/local/mysql/bin` is how the system would find MySQL. Reinstalling MySQL was not the right solution, selectively adding MySQL's `bin` directory to your path would have been the right way to proceed.

Comment: I did remove Mysql that was installed in the usr/local... I think my problem started because at some point I was using Macports or I did use the Hivelogic installation for mysql and ruby. This was before RVM. Now I'm using brew and I cleaned up my system a bit. so removing those lines from .profile and reinstalling mysql with brew did work well

Answer (score 3):

First, use `rvm info` and make sure the values reported are sane and what you expect.

As of this moment, RVM is at version 1.10.0. If `rvm -v` shows a lower version number, run `rvm get head;rvm reload` to update to the current version. That step alone can fix all sorts of issues.

To switch from a RVM controlled Ruby back to the version installed in your Mac by Apple, use:

```
rvm system
```

That should allow you to do:

```
which ruby
```

and get:

```
/usr/bin/ruby
```

or:

```
ruby -v
```

and get something like:

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin10.0]
```

To return to a RVM controlled Ruby, use: `rvm 1.9.2` or `rvm default` if you have set up a default Ruby.

If you haven't set up a default Ruby, I recommend you do so, using: `rvm 1.9.2 --default`, substituting whatever version of Ruby you want as your default.

You do NOT have to install a version of 1.8.7 under RVM's control if you don't want to, however, if you intend to modify the 1.8.7 owned by the system by adding or changing gems do so carefully. That version was installed for Apple's use and you are piggybacking on it and changes could affect the use of certain apps or future apps installed by Apple.

If you need to add gems or tweak 1.8.7, I'd recommend using RVM's `rvm install 1.8.7` into your sandbox, and go from there. At that point you can eschew using the system version of Ruby 1.8.7, and leave it alone for Apple's apps.

If all you want to do is install MacVIM, you can accomplish what you want, which is to tell the system that the RVM versions are NOT installed, by temporarily tweaking your PATH variable to NOT include the RVM controlled Rubies in your `~/.rvm` directory.

You can do that by editing PATH, or by temporarily modifying your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`, whichever has the RVM initialization in it. Open a new shell, run your install steps, then revert the file.

There are many ways to get where you want to go.

Comment: I did the steps above... I still can't go back to the system version installed ruby. When I run ruby -v I still see the 1.9.2 intead of the 1.8.7

Comment: @Marrento, Run `rvm info` and append the output to your original question please.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try: `rvm use system`?! Or `rvm use system --default` to use system Ruby every time.

Comment: When I try that and then ruby -v it shows 192 as my system... but my system is 187 as I can see if I run /usr/bin/ruby -v

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install 1.8.7:

```
rvm install 1.8.7
```

Then you need to tell RVM you want to use this one as the default:

```
rvm use 1.8.7 --default
```

Comment: Not excatly what I want to do.... and for reference I do have have 187 installed through rvm. What i Want is to have my ruby system to go back to 187 that comes with osx

Comment: Then what is it you want to do? If the system Ruby is 1.9.2 there's nothing you *should* do to change it. Use RVM and set 1.8.7 as your default. That's the easiest way.

Comment: I'm having problems installing macvim.... it does not compile well with 192... the doc says to run rvm system, brew install macvim. the problem is that the doc is assuming the ruby system is 187. I can see the 187 if I run /usr/bin/ruby -v

Comment: If you `rvm use 1.8.7` then it will use the 1.8.7 version of Ruby.

Comment: So just `install` 1.8.7 with RVM and `use` it.

Comment: It does not compile with the rvm version.... that is why the doccumentation uses rvm system as the first step. I did try with RVM and it did not work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the system is not working right for you, but installing 1.8.7 and using it should resolve the compilation error for macvim.  Instead of "rvm system", run

```
rvm install 1.8.7
rvm use 1.8.7
```

That should resolve it.